# Bind a ColdFusion SMS gateway to a specific IP address

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, sms-gateway

I am running ColdFusion 10 Enterprise on a windows server that has multiple IP addresses assigned to it.

I can bind my HTTP traffic to a specific IP address using IIS bind (and or changing the tomcat server.xml connector).

But I am trying to bind the ColdFusion SMS Gateway to a specific IP so that SMPP traffic comes from the specific IP I want to bind it to in order to get through a clients firewall.

Is it possible to bind the SMS Gateway to a specific IP, is this a tomcat config issue, a JVM parameter, or is their a way to configure the SMS Gateway directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ColdFusion administrator Event Gateways > Gateway Instances

You can have a .cfg file in Gateway Config where you can specify the IP address and Port

```
#
# SMSGateway configuration file
# Test server config
#

# Type of binding.Value can be either transciever,transmitter or receiver
binding=transciever

# This is the IP address of SMSC
ip-address=102.208.328.100

# Port to bind to
port=80001
```

Comment: Here is a [documentation reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec16809-7ff9.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-77ac) explaining the config file usage a bit.